# PHP/MYSQL: getting value from primary column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a script where I am just trying to return information when I send in an id via ajax to a php script, query the DB and return the name associated with the id.

Here is the php:

```
$userId = $_REQUEST['id'];
// Make a MySQL Connection
require('/php/dbconnect.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE id='".$userId."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$returnJson = '{';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $returnJson .= 'userName: "' . $row['userName'] . '"';
}

$returnJson .= '}';
echo $returnJson;
```

I have 2 records in the member table. The primary id's are 1 and 2. When I request this page via ajax and pass in either 1 or 2 as parameter "id" I don't get the name back.

All that is returned is "{}";

I know that everything is working on the front-end because I get atleast get "{}" back.

I have checked that there is a column named "userName" in the DB. I also know that my connection to the DB works as no mysql errors return, and (using the same db connect script) I can write to the member table just fine.

Any ideas why this is not returning anything.

Comment: FYI: PHP has a [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) function

Comment: I'd try dumping the SQL command and putting it in phpmyadmin. You'll see right away if something's broken.

Comment: Yeah, I have to do it this way because I am testing on a free server that adds some ads right at the end of the return, so I add a unique string after the parts I return and split it with JS on the front-end, and then convert it to JSON there.

Comment: @Czechnology, I ran the sql command in phpMyAdmin and it brought up the correct row highlighting the correct column.

Comment: The answers below aren't helpful?

Comment: @Dale, do you even get any results when you'd run `SELECT * FROM member` in your script? Have you got the correct database chosen?

Comment: @Czechnology, yeah correct db is chosen. The same connection methods are used to write to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

1. Don't use request. Use $_GET or $_POST
2. NeverNEVERNVNERNVNER put a variable right into an sql statement like that. If you arent going to use [PDO and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) make sure you [escape your variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
3. And the part that might be the answer... Try not putting quotes around the variable, i believe in the newer versions of mysql you can but in the older versions if you put quotes around something that was an integer field it wouldnt run correctly.

   ```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($userId);
   ```

Comment: changed to $_GET. I get a sql syntax error using: $sql='SELECT * FROM member WHERE id=' . mysql_real_escape_string($userId);

Answer (score 0):

Is column id a string type or integer type? If it is an integer, you should take the single quotes out of the query string. That might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM member WHERE id=' . intval($userId);
```

Comment: I get the same thing with this, just "{}"

Answer (score 0):

The return only being {} tells me that your loop is never even executing so it is not finding any results.  Id try echoing out your $sql variable and copy/paste it into your sql and see what it spits out.